# Get Facebook image URL

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I want to backup all Facebook photos from a user with a webapp made in PHP/Laravel. What I do right now is:

1. I first get all albums with `/me/albums`
2. Then I get all photos from each album with `/<album id>/photos`
3. And then I retrieve each photo with `/<photo id>/picture?type=normal`

And that gets me this:

```js
Facebook\FacebookResponse::__set_state(array(
   'httpStatusCode' => 302,
   'headers' => 
  array (
    'x-app-usage' => '{"call_count":0,"total_cputime":0,"total_time":0}',
    'location' => 'https://scontent.fros6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/s720x720/241688_10150189954577077_6076941_o.jpg?_nc_cat=106&ccb=2&_nc_sid=e007fa&_nc_ohc=6BG0bnvmDO0AX-ayiLu&_nc_ht=scontent.fros6-1.fna&tp=7&oh=2eb322e48d2bcba4c4f06b95d8803922&oe=5FE0AF19',
    'expires' => 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT',
    'x-fb-request-id' => 'AV2g1mnIDjWDzIgHyD48oNx',
    'strict-transport-security' => 'max-age=15552000; preload',
    'x-fb-trace-id' => 'E5eCApEMOPW',
    'facebook-api-version' => 'v9.0',
    'content-type' => 'image/jpeg',
    'x-fb-rev' => '1003022644',
    'cache-control' => 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
    'vary' => 'Accept-Encoding',
    'pragma' => 'no-cache',
    'access-control-allow-origin' => '*',
    'x-fb-debug' => '9brMqjQf3QpZ95/RjANHrhZvYY30VzEivA91+bsysa+SwAib5U6gZl5jlqjOscOusDviJe0wjoCuIJoyc67bbQ==',
    'content-length' => '0',
    'date' => 'Sun, 22 Nov 2020 17:22:05 GMT',
    'alt-svc' => 'h3-29=":443"; ma=3600,h3-27=":443"; ma=3600',
  ),
   'body' => '',
   'decodedBody' => 
  array (
  ),
   'request' => 
  Facebook\FacebookRequest::__set_state(array(
     'app' => 
    Facebook\FacebookApp::__set_state(array(
       'id' => '<hidden>',
       'secret' => '<hidden>',
    )),
     'accessToken' => <hidden>,
     'method' => 'GET',
     'endpoint' => '/10150189954577077/picture?type=normal',
     'headers' => 
    array (
      'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    ),
     'params' => 
    array (
    ),
     'files' => 
    array (
    ),
     'eTag' => NULL,
     'graphVersion' => 'v9.0',
  )),
   'thrownException' => NULL,
))
```

So what I need from there is the location. I store that object in $response. But I can't do $response['headers'] because it says is not an array (using json_encode gives and empty array) and also can't do $response->headers or $response->headers() because it says it's protected.
Who do I access image location within that Facebook Response?

Comment: https://github.com/facebookarchive/php-graph-sdk/blob/master/docs/reference/FacebookResponse.md

Comment: Edit with ->getHeaders() and this url and I put as right answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP SDK apparently does not have a dedicated section in the FB docs any more, they are redirecting directly to GitHub.

If you check the /docs/reference folder there and look for the class in question, you can find the available public methods listed there though.

https://github.com/facebookarchive/php-graph-sdk/blob/master/docs/reference/FacebookResponse.md

> **getHeaders()**
> public array getHeaders()
> Returns the response headers that were returned.